# Using async await on promise in svelte (#await) is not returning the desired data that is formatted in a later function call

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, fetch-api, svelte

I am currently working with a API that does not return JSON. To get around this, I take the response and push it to a array (while formatting it to remove any indentation and split each number in the response). I then use this array of 183 numbers and run a for loop against an array with 183 characters to generate an object (with custom key value pairs) from the response.

Where things get confusing is when I start to use the data in my HTML. Usually you can just say `<p>{data.overallRank}</p>` but I am getting the error that the object is undefined. This makes sense because the `data = {}` was not created until the function ran.

After searching for a solution, I cam across svelte await blocks. You can read on them here and look at the tutorial: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/await-blocks

After trying to implement this feature, I have the following code:

```js
let playerStats = []
    let proxy = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/"
    let url =  proxy + "https://secure.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/index_lite.ws?player=Hess"
    const data = {};
    
    let promise = getPlayer();
    async function getPlayer() {
        return await fetch(url).then((response) => response.text())
            .then((data) => {
                return data;
            });
        }

getPlayer().then((playerData) => {
// format data
  playerStats.push(playerData.replace(/\n/ig, ",").split(','));
  console.log(playerStats);

// Begin object generation
// names array shortened
let names = ["overallRank", "overallLvl", "overallXP", "attRank", ]
  
const data = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < playerStats[0].length; i++) {
        data[names[i]] = playerStats[0][i];
    }
console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<main>

{#await promise}
    <p>Search for a Player...</p>
{:then data}
    <p>The data is {data}</p>
{/await}

</main>
```

- I suggest throwing this code in a svelte editor which you can find here: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/await-blocks

The issue with this code is that it is printing out the data from the `return data`, which returns the unformatted data and not the object.

I want to return the object that is created after the second function `getplayer().then()...` so I can use that object throughout my HTML.

I hope I explained things well and thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is returning the formatted data because that what is returned by the `promise` function. In order to get the formatted data, you have to add the formatting to the chain of `promise`

```js
async function getPlayer() {
  return await fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((playerData) => {
       // here your transformation
       // do not forget to actually return something
       return data;
    });
```

Comment: I attempted to do this before posting and I wasn’t able to get it to work. The reason it wasn’t working was trivial and I fixed my errors/typos and now it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You were actually very close to sorting it out, just a bit of confusion regarding how promises work I believe.

All you need to do is format your data within the block where the data is handled following the fetch & decode operations:

```js
  async function getPlayer() {
    return await fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((data) => {
        return formatData(data);
      });
  }
```

Your `formatData()` function is essentially there already, you just need minor changes in your code:

```js
  function formatData(playerData) {
    playerStats.push(playerData.replace(/\n/ig, ",").split(','));
    console.log(playerStats);

    // Begin object generation
    // names array shortened
    let names = ["overallRank", "overallLvl", "overallXP", "attRank", ]
  
    const data = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < playerStats[0].length; i++) {
      data[names[i]] = playerStats[0][i];
    }
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  }
```

Finally, you do not need to explicitly declare a promise to use it in an `{#await}` block, you know `getPlayer()` returns a promise, so you can directly use that instead:

```js
<main>
{#await getPlayer()}
    <p>Search for a Player...</p>
{:then data}
    <p>Overall Rank: {data.overallRank}</p>
{/await}
</main>
```

[See functioning REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/70bb412acad94c3ab4bc54e5bb3da312?version=3.24.0)